# tabnew is not working in Gvim

Tags: vim, vi

I have opened a file in `gvim`.
When I want to open another file in `gvim` , I use following command.

> :tabnew `pwd`

and then press <kbd>tab</kbd> button. 
But <kbd>tab</kbd> is not expanding pwd instead it is adding  `^I

> :tabnew `pwd`^I^I^I

Earlier it was working.

`pwd` is nor expanding  in gvim whether I use it with `tabnew` or `sp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `compatible` option in your vim session by  typing in command line `:set compatible?`

If the result is:

- **`compatible`** : you need to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>
- **`nocompatible`** : you  need to type    <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

in order to get the expansion in command line.

---

For more about that: `:help cmdline-completion`